# How to print the number of elements in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, size

How do I make it so I can enter 10 or less elements into an array, and then print the number or elements??

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int a[MAX_SIZE], i;
    printf("Enter up to %d different numbers seperated by spaces: \n", MAX_SIZE);
    for(i=0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);


    printf("Length: %lu\n", sizeof(MAX_SIZE));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your `scanf()` works in accordance to your `printf` instruction?

Comment: Are you trying to read `0..10` Numbers and then print them?

Comment: `sizeof(MAX_SIZE));` or `sizeof(a));`....?

Comment: Just add a counter to keep track to the number of entries. `int cnt = 0;` then `for(i=0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) { scanf("%d", &a[i]); cnt++; }`

Comment: sizeof(a) / sizeof(int) would return the number of elements

Comment: The number of elements in the array is `MAX_SIZE`. So print `MAX_SIZE`.

Comment: Your size will always be `MAX_SIZE * sizeof (int)`

Answer (score 1):

Please close the for loop while storing data and add another loop before print.

Comment: `Number of element` refers to the count, not the numbers itselves.

Comment: It says "Number or elements" not "number of elements" thank you.

Comment: It's disputed. It was the title I was referring to. However, the coding logic supports my version, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code.

This code takes *upto* `MAX_SIZE` [`10` here] integer inputs and print the number of elemnts. You can stop the `scanf()` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> [`EOF`].

<sup>IMHO, this is the logical approach to end the input, because if you want to end the input based on some particular number, you can't have that number stored in your array.</sup>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int arr[MAX_SIZE] = {0, };       //initialize the array

    printf("Enter the numbers one by one ==> \n");

    for (count = 0; count < MAX_SIZE; count ++)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &arr[count]) == EOF)
            break;
    }

    printf("Number of elements into the array %d\n", count);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
int main()
{
    int a[MAX_SIZE], i,count=0;
    printf("Enter up to %d different numbers seperated by spaces: \n", MAX_SIZE);
    for(i=0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if(a[i] == -1)          // Use any number to break the loop
            break;              // Break the loop
        count++;                // Count number of elements
    }

    printf("Length: %d", count );  //Print number of elements

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using any counter variable you can count the number of scanned elements and using that variable you can print also..

```
int main()
{
int a[MAX_SIZE], i,count=0;
printf("Enter up to %d different numbers seperated by spaces: \n", MAX_SIZE);
for(i=0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    if(a[i] == 0)           // Use any number for breaking  loop
        break;              // break the loop
    count++;                // for Counting number of elements
}

printf("number of scanned elements: %d", count );  //Print number of elements

for(i=0;i<count;i++) // for printing upto scanned numbers
printf("%d\n",a[i]);

return 0;
}
```

We cant find out that which are scanned elements in one array. Because array can hold garbage values. So, maintain any counter variables for counting the number of elements scanning when you want to scan less than actual array boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Your size will **always** be `MAX_SIZE * sizeof(int);` (which is `10 * 4-bytes per int` in your case). Test by replacing your `printf` with:

```
printf("Length: %d\nsize  : MAX_size * sizeof (int): %lu\n", MAX_SIZE, MAX_SIZE * sizeof (int));
```

**output:**

```
Length: 10
size  : MAX_SIZE * sizeof (int): 40
```

**Note:** The storage size for an integer can very from hardware-to-hardware, so always use `sizeof(int)` in your computations.

---

I apologize, I see, you want a way to enter less than 10 and still print the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int a[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
    int i = 0;;
    int cnt = 0;

    printf("Enter up to %d different numbers seperated by spaces (ctrl+d when done): \n", MAX_SIZE);

    while (i < MAX_SIZE)
    {
        if (scanf("%d%*c", &a[i]) < 1)
            break;
        i++;
    }

    cnt = i;
    i = 0;

    printf ("\nPrinting elements using while loop:\n\n");
    while (a[i])
    {
        printf ("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
        i++;
    }

    /* or */
    printf ("\nPrinting elements using for loop:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        printf ("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);


    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/arrcnt
Enter up to 10 different numbers seperated by spaces (ctrl+d when done):
1 2 3 4 5

Printing elements using while loop:

a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 3
a[3] = 4
a[4] = 5

Printing elements using for loop:

a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 3
a[3] = 4
a[4] = 5
```

You can either keep a `count` or by initializing your array to zero, you can use a `while` loop checking for entries. (note: a '0' entered will not work with the `while` method, so it is only useful for values > 0) Also **note:** the use of the format string in `scanf` to consume the trailing `newline`. This can save you headaches later.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is not 4 bytes on every platform (and of course, it is not 4 bytes by the C standard).

Comment: Correct, that's why I **qualified** the response with **in your case** and used `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: How do you know OP's case?

Comment: `SWAG` - that `sizeof(int)` works the same on his system as it does on a standard PC.

Comment: I'm not sure what `SWAG` means, and I'm not sure there's a definition for what a "standard PC" is. In any case, OP doesn't mention anything about his or her system, nor about the outcome of any of the printouts. So for all you know it can be a 16-bit architecture with a designated compiler which uses 2-byte `int` (for example, MSP430).

Answer (score 0):

just add these to your code

```
for (i = 0; i< MAX_SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("%d",a[i]);
}
```

also add curly brackets to your loop

```
for (i = 0; i<MAX_SIZE; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
```

Comment: 1. check the title of the question. 2. for single line instruction, `{}` is not a _MUST_.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as following, Enter 0 as input where you want to stop entering more elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int a[MAX_SIZE], i;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter up to %d different numbers seperated by spaces: \n", MAX_SIZE);
    for(i=0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {  
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

        if(!a[i])
            break;

        count++;
    }


    printf("Length: %lu\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```